# How to combine parts of pipe to a function?

Tags: powershell

To have a "grep"-like experience in Powershell, I use this (e.g. to find a process with "foo" in its name):

`Get-Process | Out-String -Stream | Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern "foo"`

I would like to write a function Grep(), that takes input from the pipe, that does the same. Basically I am looking for a way to combine the last two pipe elements. So that I could simply write:

`Get-Process | Grep foo`

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [the `$input` automatic variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_automatic_variables#input) to automatically enumerate any pipeline input provided, then grab the value of the first command line argument from `$args`:

```
function grep {
    $input |Out-String -Stream |Select-String -SimpleMatch -Pattern $args[0]
}
```

Now you can do:

```
Get-Process |grep foo
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you. This is why I love this site :-)